# windows server admin account recovery

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I have created an active directory organization in windows server 2012 remotely. I had to remove that AD so i removed it from the server by going to the Server->Manage->Remove Roles and features and after that just followed that procedure.

It asked me for a new password which i have given and remember it. after removing the AD server was restarted and i got disconnected from the server and could not login again. is there any possibility that i can login again? the administrator of the server has told me that i have changed all the credentials and even he can not login to the server

Comment: To reset the Windows Password, you would need your Microsoft Windows 2012 DVD

Comment: Given physical access to the server, there are [lots of options](https://superuser.com/q/72244/96662) for resetting the administrator password.  But first, what exactly is stopping you from logging in given that you say you remember the new password?  If it is just the firewall, you probably just need to give the new password to whoever has physical access to the server.

Comment: Have you tried to connect as a local Administrator? Here is a topic on how to make it. https://serverfault.com/questions/578598/logging-in-with-local-admin-account-after-joining-domain

Comment: that is not connecting by local administrator as i have deleted by mistake the local admin .One of colleague has done it for  me thanks all of you